# I need help keeping my application running

Tags: reactjs, docker, express

I have a React application on a node express server running on a docker container. The container runs just fine and the application runs for a few hours and then I check and it has stopped. I believe the server is crashing inside the container. I don't know how to check or fix this. The application runs fine locally. I have done research and implemented graceful shutdowns and eliminated the use of tool

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('../database');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/people', (req, res) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id DESC', (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.send(results);
    }
  });
})

app.post('/people', (req, res) => {
  const { person } = req.body;
  db.query(`INSERT INTO people (person) VALUES (?)`, [person], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(201);
    }
  });
})

app.put('/people', (req, res) => {
  const { id, person } = req.body;
  db.query('UPDATE people SET person = ? WHERE id = ?', [person, id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(201);
    }
  });
})

app.delete('/people', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  db.query('DELETE FROM people WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(201);
    }
  });
})

app.options('/people', (req, res) => {
  db.query('DELETE FROM people', (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(201);
    }
  });
})

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port:${port}...`)
});

const closeProcess = async (signal) => {
  console.log(`\n${signal} signal received: Process Terminating!`)
  await db.end(async (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log('Disconnected from MySql DB!')
        await server.close(() => {
          console.log('Server closed!');
        })
        console.log('Process Terminated!')
      }
      process.exit(signal === 'SIGINT' || signal === 'SIGTERM' ? 0 : 1)
    });
}
process.on('uncaughtException', closeProcess)
process.on('unhandledRejection', closeProcess)
process.on('SIGINT', closeProcess)
process.on('SIGTERM', closeProcess)
```

s in my container like npm. Any ideas?

Comment: You need access to logging somewhere that shows you why your server is aborting.  There should be some sort of output to either stdio or stderr from the server or some diagnostics from the container itself if the container is running into some limit and shutting down the server.  Probably not much we can do by just looking at the code.  You need to capture some diagnostics.

Comment: You can use tools like [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) or [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/). It will help with incident like this.